# will mono let me work on existing code in linux?

Tags: .net, linux, mono, rider

I primarily use linux for development. I have inherited an old .net mvc project. I'd like to not have to use a windows vm to run visual studio.

Is it possible to run Rider with mono to work on the existing .NET code on my linux box? If not, is there another option for linux? Should I put off using this setup until I can talk the client into migrating to .NET core?

Comment: Yes, this is the whole purpose of Rider. That being said, you should convince your client to migrate sooner rather than later, as .NET Framework is being put out to pasture in favor of .NET Core anyway. As announced at last week's Microsoft conference, .NET Framework should now considered to be strictly in maintenance mode.

Comment: please make your comment an answer. Also, can you provide a link to back up the conference thing? I was unable to find it in a search.

Answer (score 0):

Yeshua, the link with the info mentioned by Josh is https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/

Regarding your question, I don't have experience moving a classic .Net project to Linux but remember you are building with Mono but the application have to run in IIS over Windows Server and you can face some incompatibilities.

---